# What XSS attacks could somebody perform through an iframe?

Tags: xss, iframe

If a potential attacker was able to upload a cross-origin `<iframe>` element to your website as a post of some sort, what could they actually do through it? I know that cross-origin `<iframe>` elements are able to do simple stuff like using JavaScript's `alert()` method, but what else could they do to the page it was uploaded to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the iframe isn't sandboxed (via the optional HTML attribute), the main thing that it could do (aside from displaying / playing content you might not want shown to the user / associated with your site) is use top-level navigation to go from the legit page (where the iframe is hosted) to a spoofed, look-alike page with a similar domain. However, the attacker completely controls this spoofed page. They can now try to trick the user into interacting with it as though it's your own, trusted page. Examples include stealing credentials (phishing), authorizing access to third-party services like Google, capturing content that you type or upload, or tricking users with plausible-seeming misinformation.

The main other thing that an iframe can attempt is window messaging (that is, using `window.postMessage()`) to try and attack the parent page. Obviously this only works if the parent is

- Listening for (has set up an event handler for) window messages
- Is either not filtering the origin of the messages or expects them from the iframed site
- Is either not filtering the source window of those messages or expects them from the iframe
- Can be meaningfully exploited via a maliciously crafted window message

and none of those are at all guaranteed. However, it could be attempted, since unlike most cases, the untrusted page has a `Window` object (specifically, `window.parent`) for the target site.

Otherwise, there's basically nothing that a cross-origin iframe can do to the parent page directly. Same origin policy for iframes is pretty strong by default. For example, even though top-level navigation is allowed by default, the iframe can't get the parent page's URL. Nor can it navigate to e.g. a `javascript:` URI, which would execute in the context of the parent page.

---

Note that if you're considering doing this, you really should take advantage of iframe sandboxing anyhow. The [`sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) is useful for adding additional restrictions to the content in an iframe, either beyond what same-origin policy already enforces, or even making iframes that are actually same-origin have restricted permissions. It's optional (without it, the usual restrictions on cross-origin iframes still apply, though) but it's worth using for extra security. Note the list of restrictions that you can lift (through attribute values) if you want to consider some other things that iframed content may be able to do. (Note that many of those things are always blocked, both without `sandbox` and with the access specifically granted, for cross-origin sandboxes.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any server request? `<iframe src=//yourserver.ping></iframe>` or  `<iframe src=file:///etc/passwd></iframe>` give a try you might get easy SSRF.

Answer (score 1):

This malicious embedded bad pixel / iframe plant gets to a) know if it is running inside an iframe, the referrer, and therefore either pop out / create a pop up top level window, (breaking free of the sniffer also if you swap roles) or shutdown or redirect etc. b) is treated as tainted memory and can be extremely firewalled with the right CORS headers, but also if you allow script-src: * or be silly you probably could get into trouble. The only way to move things between the two is using a message passing thing - service workers which can only send textual signals probably filter weird characters out and are rate limited (after 30 seconds its harder to exfiltrate large chunks via this pipe).

A regular script tag embedded in the body of the main page would be much more dangerous - it could log all keystrokes and monitor all interactions and everything clicked. Maybe jam a javascript into a SVG that acts like an image? Tricky.